# jquery mobile multi - page loading twice

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

The problem is that in android emulator,opera mini or opera mobile the page is loaded once.
But in blackberry 8530 native browser, **the page loads twice**.

The problem occurs when I use

```
echo '<a href="link.php" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Go to link</a>';
```

But if I put rel="external", then it refreshes the age and the ajax animation disappears.

```
  echo '<a href="link.php" data-role="button" data-icon="star" rel="external">
Go to link</a>';
```

**So what is the standard way to go to next page without loosing any animation and loading page only once?**

Note:I dont use those one page # navigation like `<a href="#link.php">`, nobody can make a big website in single page, single page template is just impractical, and worst form of making a webpage. So I use normal `<a href="link.php">` to go to next page.**Is the problem in using multipage template?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using target="_blank"? This is a standard function of the A tag and is supported by the BlackBerry Browser.

Go to link will open a new window.